# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1 when doing group by on two columns and transforming the group to calculate counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame, which looks like the following:

```
 df =

 user_id  item_id  time  location
  u1      i1        t1.   l1
  u2      i1        t2    l2
  u1      i2        t3    l1
  u3      i2        t4    l2
  u4      i1        t5    l1
  u5      i1        t6    l1
```

Expected Output:

```
  df =
 user_id  item_id  time  location count
  u1      i1       t1.   l1         3
  u2      i1       t2    l2         1
  u1      i2       t3    l1         1
  u3      i2       t4    l2         1
  u4      i1       t5    l1         3
  u5      i1       t6    l1         3
```

I am simply trying to group by itemid and location and compute the number of times each group occurs.

This is the code, which works:

```
 df.groupby(['item_id', 'location']).size()
```

But, I want to attach this grouping back to the df:

So, I did the following to achieve this:

```
  data.groupby(['item_id', 'customer_zipcode'])['user_id','time'].transform('size')
```

But, I get the following error:

```
 IndexError: Column(s) ['user_id', 'time'] already selected
```

Then, I did this:

```
 data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])['user_id','time'].transform('count')
```

It works, but does not give the desired output.

I also tried this:

```
   data.groupby(['item_id', 'location']).transform('sum')
```

But, this gives a different error:

```
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'
```

So, how to group by two columns, calculate the occurences (counts) and attach it back to the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working if select only one value after `groupby` in need one new column:

```
data['count1'] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])['user_id'].transform('size')
data['count2'] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])['user_id'].transform('count')
print (data)
  user_id item_id time location  count1  count2
0      u1      i1  t1.       l1       3       3
1      u2      i1   t2       l2       1       1
2      u1      i2   t3       l1       1       1
3      u3      i2   t4       l2       1       1
4      u4      i1   t5       l1       3       3
5      u5      i1   t6       l1       3       3
```

There is difference between this methods - `size` count only groups, but `count` is used for count values of columns with exclude `NaN`s, so working for test multiple columns:

```
#no missing values, same output
data[['count2','count3']] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])[['user_id', 'time']].transform('count')
print (data)
  user_id item_id time location  count2  count3
0      u1      i1  t1.       l1       3       3
1      u2      i1   t2       l2       1       1
2      u1      i2   t3       l1       1       1
3      u3      i2   t4       l2       1       1
4      u4      i1   t5       l1       3       3
5      u5      i1   t6       l1       3       3
```

---

```
print (data)
  user_id item_id time location
0      u1      i1  t1.       l1
1      u2      i1  NaN       l2
2      u1      i2   t3       l1
3     NaN      i2   t4       l2
4     NaN      i1   t5       l1
5      u5      i1   t6       l1

#tested each column separately
data[['count2','count3']] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])[['user_id', 'time']].transform('count')
print (data)
  user_id item_id time location  count2  count3
0      u1      i1  t1.       l1       2       3
1      u2      i1  NaN       l2       1       0
2      u1      i2   t3       l1       1       1
3     NaN      i2   t4       l2       0       1
4     NaN      i1   t5       l1       2       3
5      u5      i1   t6       l1       2       3
```

If test multiple columns with `size` if fail, I guess bug (or some notice it has no sense test multiple columns, because not exclude NaNs, so always all columns has same values):

```
data[['count2','count3']] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])[['user_id', 'time']].transform('size')

print (data)
```

> IndexError: Column(s) ['user_id', 'time'] already selected

Because error is possible verify it if use each column seoparately:

```
data['count2'] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])['user_id'].transform('size')
data['count3'] = data.groupby(['item_id', 'location'])[ 'time'].transform('size')
print (data)

  user_id item_id time location  count2  count3
0      u1      i1  t1.       l1       3       3
1      u2      i1  NaN       l2       1       1
2      u1      i2   t3       l1       1       1
3     NaN      i2   t4       l2       1       1
4     NaN      i1   t5       l1       3       3
5      u5      i1   t6       l1       3       3
```

Comment: yes, it is working. Do you know why we need to add one column and not `time`? How `time` is taken care of internally?

Comment: @SumitSidana - I think here it working with any column after `groupby`, why it is `indexerorr` it is weird, looks like bug.

Comment: is it working for you if  you add both columns `user_id` and `time`?

Comment: `time` column shouldn't be modified, right? I am trying to understand the behaviour of specifying only one column.

Comment: @SumitSidana - I try edit answer for better explanation.

Comment: yes, thank you for the detailed answer. I don't have `NaN`s in my data. So both `count2` and `count3` are same.